# R Loop Runs Too Slowly

Tags: performance, r, optimization, for-loop

I have two very large data frames (50MM+ rows) and I need to run some calculations on them.  I have developed the following loop, but it runs too slowly.  I tried using apply and other methods, but I couldn't get them to work.

```
#### Sample Data
df=data.frame(id=1:10,time=Sys.time()-1:10,within5=NA)
df2=data.frame(id2=c(1,1,1,5,5,10),time2=Sys.time()-c(9,5,2,3,4,6))

#### Loop shows how many results from df2 are within 5 secs of the creation of the ID    in df
for (i in 1:length(df$id))
{
temp=df2[df2$id==df$id[i],]
df$within5[i]=sum(abs(as.numeric(difftime(temp$time2,df$time[i],units="secs")))<5)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check improvement of procedures, made larger sample data.

```
df=data.frame(id=1:100,time=Sys.time()-1:100)
df2=data.frame(id2=sample(1:100,300000,replace=T),time2=Sys.time()-sample(1:5,300000,replace=T))
```

Use function `ddply()` from package `plyr` to divide your data according to column `id2`. Then apply your function to each subset.

```
library(plyr)
df3 <- ddply(df2,"id2",function(x){ 
    data.frame(within5=sum(abs(as.numeric(difftime(x$time2,df$time[df$id==x$id2[1]],units="secs")))<5))})
```

As a result we get new data frame.

```
 head(df3)
  id2 within5
1   1    3129
2   2    3032
3   3    2935
4   4    3121
5   5    3042
6   6    2426
```

If you need column `within5` in your original data frame you can use function `merge()`.

```
df4 <- merge(df,df3,by.x="id",by.y="id2",all=T)
```

With my sample data this calculation was 10 time faster.

Comment: ...and if `plyr` has this effect, you can easily speed things up much more using `data.table`...

Answer (score 1):

Use the second id to look up the reference time, and subtract the event time from that, for your data above

```
dt <- df2$time2 - df$time[df2$id]
```

then select event ids with absolute time differences less than 5

```
okIds <- df2$id2[abs(as.numeric(dt)) < 5]
```

tabulate these, and add to your original data frame

```
df$within5 <- tabulate(okIds, max(df$id))
```

This relies on the ids being sequential integers (if not, make them a `factor()` and then use the integer encoding the results) and is very fast.